# extracting Drupal node and menu relationships with SQL

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-nodes

I am trying to untangle a complicated multi language Drupal site with custom SQL reports.
By poking around I bit I was able to construct this SQL statement which gives me all nodes and helps me find translation relationships.

```
SELECT  node.nid as node_nid, node.language as node_language, 
        node.type as node_type, node.title as node_title, 
        node.tnid as node_tnid, node.status as node_status, url.src, 
        url.dst, url.language as url_language 
FROM {node} as node 
LEFT JOIN {url_alias} as url 
      ON url.src = CONCAT('node/', node.nid) 
ORDER BY node_type, node_language, node.nid
```

Now I want to add 'permitted input formats' and publishing options for each node.  Also list all menus and what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the views module, it can save you a lot of time and save you writing custom SQL.